# Change fragment but text reamin android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this issue: when I change fragment the TextView below remain and the result is 2 TextView.

I explain better:

I have one TextView with a string "hello word"

when I change fragment I want to change the entire page and set another TextView but the result is 2 TextVIew

thanks a lot!

activityMain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#5ba4e5"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/fragment">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentText"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

this in MainActivity for change the fragment:

```
private void selectItem(int id) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
```

and this is MyFragment.java:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        // String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];
        String planet = "prova fragment";
        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentText)).setText(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what your code? if you try and have error plz send error...

Comment: I try to put code but StackOverflow says: "too much code" -.-

Comment: i cant add more code....

Comment: yes..you must first explain more about your problem then put your code

Comment: your question title is either unclear ...please correct it! and one other thing: do your googling on your question?

Comment: I found the problem! thanks anyway

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, edit your question for clarify your specific problem. Posting relevant code and detailing the error. If you find the problem, you could help to improve the community posting it as answer as well.

Comment: Good job :) plz answer your question to hlep other programmer that see your question Michele.. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

but content_frame is a FrameLayout and the fragment is a LinearLayout so I change content_frame with the id of a LinearLayout in the content_main.xml and it works.